# New top bar has introduced a design glitch

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The [new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/184638) has upset the ELU banner by pushing the central box down too far. Its ornaments no longer line up with the horizontal line.

[image: Box ornaments don't match the line]

This affects the main site and Meta.ELU.

Note: not everyone gets to see this (yet). Hopefully it can be fixed before it's generally released.

Comment: Strange, I don't see the new top bar on ELU. I do see it on MSE today. (EDIT: Oh, only mods on all sites see it.)

Comment: @Pawel. So you don't need a diamond to add "status-review" tags?

Comment: @NVZ I apologize, I should have introduced myself. I'm Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange) employee - I have some special privilege to add status- tags without diamond.

Comment: @Paweł Thanks. I did see your profile description. But it was strange that you didn't have the diamond. :)

Comment: Hadn't noticed it, but now that you point it out I see it also.

Comment: @MetaEd The glass has been broken in your head. You will never unsee it now.

Comment: @Paweł You fixed this, didn't you?

Comment: I thought we were just using a different clef going forward ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Thanks again for reporting. It now should be fixed.

[image: Fixed ornament]

Comment: Indeed it is. I've added an image here for those who can't yet see it.